Google Cloud Platform App Engine flask app gives 404 but not locally
I created a flask app that has been working until I deleted the default project to clean up. I had no versionining so the buckets were non-recoverable.
So, I created a new project and pointed my local app to that with authorization. The staging and default app buckets were created. When deploying, the process takes so long and eventually no service/instances are created.
My app.yaml looks like
runtime: python311
handlers:
-  url: /static
   static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: auto
entrypoint: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 --timeout 600 app:app 
# instance_class: F4_1G -> better scaling and access to assets on cloud 
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

I have tried everything and given all necessary permissions but nothing works. The app works just fine locally.

Your question isn't a minimal repro of the issue and lacks sufficient detail for us to provide much help. Please include all the commands, the output and the logs. Did you e.g. enable billing, create the App Engine app (before) deployment? Enable services? Is the app.yaml a recreation or the original? Is the app's source code original or recreated? Does the app run locally using the entrypoint command? Extended deployments could be a result of (App Engine) service issues which should be reflected in the logs.

I tried everything, I can run it locally. In the end, I have decided to move to cloud run to save time

Your entrypoint should be something like entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT -w 2 app:app. In addition, since you have an entrypoint with gunicorn, you MUST have gunicorn in your requirements.txt file. To simulate production locally, you MUST run with dev_appserver.py. Just running your app locally with flask run or python app.py doesn't simulate production which means your App might work locally but fail to run in production.
